# Do aspects execute in their own thread?

Tags: java, aspectj

I have a pretty short question in relation to AspectJ.

Do aspects execute from a separate thread or do they execute on the existing thread (i.e. the one your main method executes from)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They execute in the same thread where the advised code was executing. AspectJ is not concerned about threading in any way. Of course, nothing stops you from developing an aspect that, when triggered, would go on and create new threads, or schedule work to an executor service, or whatever else you might come to think of.

Answer (score 0):

It executes on the same thread that your code was initially run from. Aspects are exactly the same as normal code, it is just code that is abstracted away behind some sort of handler. You would need to inspect the code of the actual aspect to determine whether or not it is using multiple threads behind the scenes. But no, by default annotations and aspects will not be run in different threads.